Typeset main text and two commentaries but not in parallel columns
I wish to typeset Sanskrit text, with two or more commentaries and a translation. If possible I want to typeset these three or more texts one after the other on a page, and not in parallel columns.
For example, one stanza of main text will be followed by a commentary on that stanza, then the next commentary, followed by translation. All these will have different lengths. If they cannot finish on a page then they will continue on the next page. Every page will have some part of these three or four texts.
I have added an image from an old book to show what I wish to achieve. Here main text is followed by two commentaries and footnotes.

I have checked packages that achieve this using parallel columns. But I wish to do this as in traditional books.
Thank you very much.

do you need any package at all, as they are not side by side can't you simply make the source match the desired output, one paragraph of original text, then a paragraph of commentary then a paragraph of translation, then a paragraph of original text...

If you want to get fancy, you can use tcolorbox to separate the translations etc.

Will there always be exactly one stanza per page?

Thanks for the suggestions. The exact amount of text from each of the three commentaries is not fixed. So there may be 20 line explanation of just one stanza or only two lines. Sometimes there may not be even space for original one complete stanza on a page and sometimes you may fit more than one. I will check tcolorbox. I don't need some package but an idea how to go about doing this. Thank you once again.

@David Thank you for your suggestion. To further clarify my problem, how to take the remaining part of each of the paragraphs to the next page and do this automatically? Only on the last page of chapter there may be fewer parts present. Thank you.

so if the stanza of the main text is long you want to split it and split the commentaries and translation not have all the main stanza first then the commentaries for that stanza following, possibly on later page?

Yes. In manually typesetting each page, only few lines of the main text are chosen, and some part of all the commentaries is there on the same page. For that to achieve, manually every page is set by varying the height chosen for each part. Can we allocate certain part of each page for say main text, commentary one and so on? The great thing would be to have some flexibility in terms of allocated height by a line or so. Once the allocated part is consumed that particular commentary text can continue on the next page. Thank you.
